# input without border with position fixed

Tags: html, css

How can I make a input look like that:
[image]

I want it to have no borders, be full-width of div and fixed to bottom. my actual code is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write message and press enter..." maxlength="150" required>
```

when I add a `width:100%` attribute it's bigger than width of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

As you might already have a `padding` and `border`. After that, please add:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

And you are done.